# Higgs to 4 lepton decay involving virtual photon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, higgs, large-hadron-collider

In Gluon gluon production of Higgs, is it possible for higgs to decay to following channels:

1. A pair of virtual photons which then decay to a pair of leptons each.
2. To an on shell Z boson and a virtual photon and then each of them decays to a pair of leptons?

I am asking this question in reference to the standard model or (higgs) effective field theory for higgs to 4 lepton channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Feynman rules feature neither a vertex $H\gamma\gamma$, nor a vertex $HZ\gamma$, what you considered requires higher-order corrections. Here is the leading-order tree diagram and the next-leading-order diagrams matching your criteria, i.e. 4 leptons in the final state, with a vertex $Z l^+l^-$ or $\gamma l^+l^-$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if the higgs itself is off shell?

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: In the higgs to gamma gamma diagram you have shown, on including the virtual top quark or W boson loop, are the photons produced off shell? If they are on shell, I cannot get a pair of on shell leptons from them. As I want to have  4 leptons to be the final particles to get Higgs to 4 lepton channel

Comment: The photons could be off-shell and give you 4 leptons, sure. That's a higher-order correction which may be incorporated in present theoretical predictions. I have not checked in a long while. Are you planning to compute one of those?

Comment: Not yet, maybe later. I came across such Feynman diagrams when I generated events for higgs to 4 leptons for my Higgs EFT study. So was thinking about the validity of such diagrams.

Comment: What do you mean,  if you accept loops? Loops aren't optional.

Comment: @innisfree Nope but it was not clear what the OP wanted…